# import table data and save as json documents in adls gen2 using databricks

Tags: powershell, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using the below code to generate json resultset from a sql server table.

**Powershell:**

```
$InstanceName = "SQLTEST1\ENG_TST1"
$connectionString = "Server=$InstanceName;Database=dbadb;Integrated Security=True;"

$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.sales"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"

$table.Load($result)

$table | select $table.Columns.ColumnName | ConvertTo-Json

$connection.Close()
```

Could you please guide me to store json documents in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.write.json` [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/R/write.json.html) to write to any specific location as per your need.

**Syntax:**`df.write.json('location where you want to save the json file')`

**Example:**`df.write.json("abfss://<file_system>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/iot_devices.json")`

Here are the steps to save the JSON documents to Azure Data Lake Gen2 using Azure Databricks.

**Step1:** You can use `spark.read.json` API to read the json file and create a dataframe.

**Step2:** The blob storage location can be mounted to a databricks dbfs directory, using the instructions in below doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2

**Step3:** Then use the `df.write.json` API to write to the mount point, which will write to the blob storage

For more details, refer the below articles:

[Azure Databricks – JSON files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/read-json)

**Sample notebook:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/adls-passthrough-gen2.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save file to Azure data lake gen2 in Azure databricks, please refer to the following steps

1. Create an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account.

```
az login
az storage account create \
    --name <account-name> \
    --resource-group <group name> \
    --location westus \
    --sku Standard_RAGRS \
    --kind StorageV2 \
    --enable-hierarchical-namespace true
```

2. Create a service principal and assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to the sp in the scope of the Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account

```
az login

az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --scopes /subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

3. Create a Spark cluster in Azure Databricks
4. mount Azure data lake gen2 in Azure databricks(python)

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<appId>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<clientSecret>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token",
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1",
mount_point = "/mnt/flightdata",
extra_configs = configs)
```

4. save json to azure data lake gen2

```
dbutils.fs.put("/mnt/flightdata/<file name>", """
<json string>
""", True)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ITHelpGuy Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?