# possible ways to take Azure Databricks backup?

Tags: azure, databricks, backup

what are the possible ways to take Azure Databricks Backup and to store in azure blob storage. How to automate the backup process regularly. I tried to search some of the articles but i haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Hi Kartheek, I am not sure about the backups, but it would be easier for someone to answer if you can mention what it is that you would like to backup ? is it the notebooks (check in to git repo) or data (external table/volumes ?) or table (external table and backup DDLs) or any other assets ?

Comment: Hi, I want to take backup of all the data whatever exist in Databricks like clusters, notebooks and tables etc.

Comment: Again as I mentioned, this is not my area of expertise, but consider using IaaC for creating clusters and Git Repos for code, External Tables and Volumes for data in databricks - Have a look at the databricks Rest API/CLI...I am sure someone more knowledgeable can give a better solution, but the points I mentioned should give you a good starting point for reference...

Answer (score 0):

Delta tables are **ACID** compliant, they can store previous versions of your data based on the retention period you specify.
If you accidentally overwrite your table with incorrect data or drop your table, you can use Delta Lake's time travel feature to revert to previous versions within the specified retention period.

Below are the steps to utilize [Delta Lake's time travel](https://delta.io/blog/2023-02-01-delta-lake-time-travel/) feature for navigating between different versions of a Delta table. Delta Lake streamlines the process of time traveling and accessing various versions of your Delta table. You can use the `history` command to display all versions of the Delta table along with their associated timestamps.

For backup tables you can create an unmanaged table for your data by using the following syntax:

```
create table <name>
using delta
location 'path_or_url_to data'
```

- You can directly access data using URLs like `abfss:// or wasbs://` in Azure Databricks.

Databricks deltas offer an efficient and structured method for creating table copies.
There are two types of delta clones: **Shallow Clone** and **Deep Clone**

A **deep clone** involves copying both the source table's data and its metadata to the clone target.

A **shallow clone** does not copy the data files to the clone target. The table metadata is the same as that of the source.

The below are the syntax for the DEEP and SHALLOW clone:

```
CREATE TABLE delta.`/data/target/` CLONE delta.`/data/source/` -- Create a deep clone of /data/source at /data/target

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE db.target_table CLONE db.source_table -- Replace the target

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS delta.`/data/target/` CLONE db.source_table -- No-op if the target table exists

CREATE TABLE db.target_table SHALLOW CLONE delta.`/data/source`

CREATE TABLE db.target_table SHALLOW CLONE delta.`/data/source` VERSION AS OF version

CREATE TABLE db.target_table SHALLOW CLONE delta.`/data/source` TIMESTAMP AS OF timestamp_expression -- timestamp can be like “2019-01-01” or like date_sub(current_date(), 1)
```

For a cluster backup solution, you can mount your storage container into Databricks using the `dbutils.fs.mount` command. After [mounting the storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts), you can configure the cluster to use the mounted location for backups.

**References:** Know more about [Azure Databricks & Version Management](https://cprosenjit.medium.com/azure-databricks-version-management-35fc78e11d7)

[Using Deep Clone for Disaster Recovery with Delta Lake on Databricks](https://www.databricks.com/wp-content/uploads/notebooks/using-deep-clone-disaster-recovery-delta-lake-databricks.html)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235137/import-table-data-and-save-as-json-documents-in-adls-gen2-using-databricks) LINK